# ggplot object not found error when adding layer with different data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with some points and I'd like to use segment to connect them

```
dummy = data.frame(GROUP=c("A","B","C","D"),
                   X = c(80,75,68,78),
                   Y=c(30, 32,36,33)

)
df= data.frame(x1 = c(80), x2 =c(78) , y1=c(30), y2 =c(33))
df
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dummy,aes(x=X,y=Y,color=GROUP)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x1,y=y1,xend= x2, yend =y2), data = df)
```

but I get this error

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'GROUP' not found
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do we have an R-FAQ for this? I think I've seen 3 in the last week...

Comment: Set `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the `geom_segment` layer.

Comment: [The best I could find](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5415132/903061) for a dupe... but I like the simplicity of this one. And the answer at the dupe is perhaps a little dated.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a nicely reproducible question which could be made into a canonical dupe!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Aesthetic mapping defined in the initial `ggplot` call will be inherited by all layers. Since you initialized your plot with `color = GROUP`, `ggplot` will look for a `GROUP` column in subsequent layers and throw an error if it's not present. There are 3 good options to straighten this out:

**Option 1:** Set `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the layer the you do not want to inherit aesthetics. This is the best choice when aesthetic exceptions are in a small number of layers.

```
ggplot(dummy,aes(x = X, y = Y, color = GROUP)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2),
               data = df,
               inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

**Option 2:** Only specify aesthetics that you want to be inherited (or that you will overwrite) in the top call - set other aesthetics at the layer level:

```
ggplot(dummy,aes(x = X, y = Y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = GROUP)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2),
               data = df)
```

**Option 3:** Specify `NULL` aesthetics on layers when they don't apply.

```
ggplot(dummy,aes(x = X, y = Y, color = GROUP)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2, color = NULL),
               data = df)
```

---

#### Which to use?

Most of the time option 1 is just fine. It can be annoying, however, if you want some aesthetics to be inherited by a layer and you only want to modify one or two. Maybe you are adding some errorbars to a plot and using the same `x` and `color` column names in your main data and your errorbar data, but your errorbar data doesn't have a `y` column. This is a good time to use Option 2 or Option 3 to avoid repeating the `x` and `color` mappings.)

Comment: for a consistent legend, option 3 could have `show.legend = FALSE` added

Comment: I get the error when `+ annotation_custom(..)`, but when `+ annotation_custom(..., inherit.aes = F)` I then see: `unused argument (inherit.aes = F)`

Comment: On further investigation, I may have stumbled upon an edgecase (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14415073/5783745), [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/756))