# How to get rid of that inner condition?

Tags: r

If argument `negation` is true then the `condition` should be negated. Is there a more convenient way to write this?

```
foo <- function (x, type, negation){
  if(type == 1){
    condition <- x > 1
    if(negation){
      condition <- !condition
    }
  }
  if(type == 2){
    condition <- x == 5
    if(negation){
      condition <- !condition
    }
  }
  x[condition]
}
```

EDIT:
example:

```
x <- 1:10

foo(x, 1, T) # 1
foo(x, 1, F) # 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
foo(x, 2, T) # 1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 10
foo(x, 2, F) # 5
```

Comment: You don't need to write `if(negation)` twice

Comment: I have edited my code according to your nice advice.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `x[condition]`, what is final result? And what is `x`? Single number?

Comment: A vector with elements which fullfill the specific condition (when negation is false) or not fulfill (if negation is true). I wondering is there any constructor in R which can simplify that `ifelse(negation, !condition, condition)`

Comment: Please post example of `x`, `type` and `negation`

Comment: Done. I need it to implement behavior of checkboxes for shiny app. The `type` is the id of checkbox and `negation` is a value of checkbox (false/true). Checkbox with `type == 1` has label: exclude values bigger than 1 from dataset. and Checkbox with `type == 2` has label: exclude values equals 5 from dataset.

Comment: @WW how many `type`'s there can be? Only 1 and 2?

Comment: plenty of types... and I will be adding more and more in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there will be many types in future, consider using S3 OOP system.
If not:

```
foo <- function(x, type, negation) {
  condition <- switch(
    type,
    `1` = x > 1,
    `2` = x == 5
  )

  x[xor(negation, condition)]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(after **@PoGibas** comment):

```
foo <- function (x, type, negation){
  if(type == 1){
    condition <- x > 1
  }
  if(type == 2){
    condition <- x == 5
  }
  if(negation){
    condition <- !condition
  }
  x[condition]
}
```

any other ideas to improve it more?

Comment: Leaving a comment here since you deleted your last question too quickly. The answer to your problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40391272/324364).

Comment: thx, I just found the soultion that it is better to leave `ggplot()` arguments empty and put'em into the specific `geom_`

Comment: Yes, that is one of three possible solutions, as outlined at the answer I linked to, although which is best depends on the situation and your preference.