# the error codes from ggplot while using geom_tex at the same time

Tags: r

I have two df that I used for plotting.

```
df <- data.frame(x2=rnorm(100),y2=rnorm(100)) %>% mutate(Class=case_when(x2>0 ~1,
                                                                         TRUE ~0))
df2<- structure(list(xpos = -2.5, ypos = -2, annotateText = structure(1L, .Label = "Text", class = "factor"), 
    hjustvar = 0, vjustvar = 0), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

My plotting codes are:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x2, y2, colour=Class)) + geom_point()+
  geom_text(data = df2, aes(x=xpos,y=ypos,hjust=hjustvar,
                                    vjust=vjustvar,label=(annotateText)))
```

When I run it, I got error codes: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Class' not found`. If I removed `colour=Class` then my codes run. What did I do wrong? I really want to have the color difference for different groups. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `color = Class` can be moved into `geom_point` as the subsequent layers can check for inheritance from the top layer as by default `inherit.aes = TRUE` in those layers

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x2, y2)) +
     geom_point(aes(color = Class)) + 
     geom_text(data = df2, aes(x = xpos,y = ypos,hjust = hjustvar,
                        vjust = vjustvar,label= annotateText))
```

Comment: May I ask why I can use `color = Class` in the first line?

Comment: Ah didn't realise it worked like that! Geoms only inherit from the initial `ggplot()` call

Comment: @Stataq The reason is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391272/ggplot-object-not-found-error-when-adding-layer-with-different-data) about inheriting

Answer (score 2):

### Your second geometry is inheriting the aesthetics you specified in your initial call to `ggplot()`

You need to specify `inherit.aes = FALSE` in your call to `geom_text()`

Ggplot geometries inherit the aesthetics from the initial call to `ggplot()`. Your aesthetic `colour = Class` that you specify in your call to `ggplot()` is inherited by `geom_point()`, resulting in the desired behaviour. Your error occurs because `geom_text()` also inherits this `colour = Class`, and subsequently crashes because `Class` isn't defined in the data it's using - `df2`.

You can fix this by specifying in `geom_text()` that you don't want to inherit any aesthetics from the initial call:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x2, y2, colour=Class)) + geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = df2, aes(x=xpos,y=ypos,hjust=hjustvar,
                            vjust=vjustvar,label=(annotateText)),
            inherit.aes = FALSE)
```